# Laravel - Use the same v-model for select form

Tags: laravel, v-model

I need to put v-model in my Category and sub category select form. Im confused

My view

```
 <div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('account_id', 'Parent Category:')!!}
     {!! Form::select('account_id', $allCategories,  ['placeholder' => 'Choose Category'])!!}
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('children', 'Child category:')!!}
     {!! Form::select('children', [], null, ['placeholder' => 'Choose child category'])!!}
</div>
```

Also
If (v-model) in subcategory is selected do not take in consideration v-model in category.

thanks

Comment: Yes you are confused hehehehe, you are mixin blade concepts with vuejs concepts if you gonna use v-model... use direct html

Comment: I would suggest watching this video https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/19 and the following 2 videos after it. It is part of a whole series so it might be worth looking watching others in there as well. Scroll down the page and there will be a list of all the videos on the right, if there are any that you feel you're not sure about then give them a go.